# How to switch between different datatemplates in listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, datatemplate

I want to have different datatemplates within a single listbox. For example I need 3 listbox items with editbox, ckeckbox and textbox.

If I have only one template everything is ok, because I can declare ListBox.ItemTemplate with DataTemplate but I can't understand how to make different templates and how switch between them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Implementing Windows Phone 7 DataTemplateSelector and CustomDataTemplateSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector)